# Multi dimensional array which takes one to multiple value in selenium IDE

Tags: selenium

```
var areaarray = new array ('Newyork','Denmark','London');

var specarray = new array ('Dental surgeon','dentist','Heart surgeon');
```

Here in this case while displaying the result it will take shows as follows:

Newyork Dental surgeon
Denmark dentist
London Heart surgeon

But I need it to display in following manner :
Newyork Dental surgeon
        dentist
        Heart surgeon
Denmark Dental surgeon
        dentist
        Heart surgeon
London Dental surgeon
        dentist
        Heart surgeon

I am using js file to write this code and fetching the result through selenium IDE by writing command

Please can anyone Help me????

Thanks in advance....!

Comment: Can you share your code implementation ?